# Tradingview Pine script plot staircase chart

Tags: pine-script

I want to plot the quality of earnings which is not available in the trading view. However, what I got is not the staircase chart. How can I plot the staircase chart? I have tried the style option in plot function and gaps option in the financial function but no luck.

```
study("Quality of earnings")

CFO = financial(syminfo.tickerid, "CASH_F_OPERATING_ACTIVITIES", "FY")
net = financial(syminfo.tickerid, "NET_INCOME", "FY")
plot(CFO/net)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will plot a stepline, overlaid on the main chart and on the left scale.

```
//@version=4
study("Quality of earnings", overlay=true, scale=scale.left)

cfo = financial(syminfo.tickerid, "CASH_F_OPERATING_ACTIVITIES", "FY")
net = financial(syminfo.tickerid, "NET_INCOME", "FY")

qoe = cfo/net

plot(qoe, style=plot.style_stepline)
```

[image: Stepline chart]

Answer (score 0):

```
study("Quality of earnings")

CFO = financial(syminfo.tickerid, "CASH_F_OPERATING_ACTIVITIES", "FY")
net = financial(syminfo.tickerid, "NET_INCOME", "FY")
plot(CFO/net)
```

Comment: study("Quality of earnings")

CFO = financial(syminfo.tickerid, "CASH_F_OPERATING_ACTIVITIES", "FY")
net = financial(syminfo.tickerid, "NET_INCOME", "FY")
plot(CFO/net)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**