# Plotting multiple graphs, some overlay, some not

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I want to create a few strategies that involve some indicators that should be plotted over the candles, others that should go into their own windows because they have different scales.

Let's say for the sake of the example that we want to plot BB and MACD in the same graph. We want the BB over the candles graph, the MACD into its own window. How do I do this? If I use "overlay=true", both are plot in the candles graph. If I try "overlay=false", then the BBs are not plotted over the candles. Plus, AFAIK we can only have one "strategy(overlay=xx)" per script.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be done in a single script in Pine. One script always pertains to a single window.
You can however have your indicator bounded to the left scale, so that it doesn't distort the main chart.
To do that, you have to enter the `scale` parameter on the `study()` function.

Like this:

```
//@version=4
study("Quality of earnings", overlay=true, scale=scale.left)

cfo = financial(syminfo.tickerid, "CASH_F_OPERATING_ACTIVITIES", "FY")
net = financial(syminfo.tickerid, "NET_INCOME", "FY")

qoe = cfo/net

plot(qoe, style=plot.style_stepline)
```

Source of this example is [Tradingview Pine script plot staircase chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65154643/tradingview-pine-script-plot-staircase-chart/)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use all indicator's calculation on your script, just remove de plotting part. Then add the same indicator to your chart layout. This way it will be placed in the bottom part (no overlay). It's a little bit strange to deal with the same code twice but is the way TV works.